# Side-channel attack

Tags: c, security

I have this piece of code given in my homework, which is part of a crackme. Now, we are asked to implement a side-channel attack on this crackme to find the right password.
I know that you can find it by looking at the time it takes to compute. This also depends on the difference of the characters.
I'm just not sure how to start coding the attack, moreover that the time varies, and is random.
By trying out a few possibilities and looking at the time it takes to print out an answer, the length of the key equals 6.

Can somebody please help?

The code fragment (written in C):

```
int compare_key() {
    unsigned int len = strlen(key_input);
    unsigned int correct_len = strlen(correct_key);
    int i, wait_time = 0, random_time, diff;
    struct timeval t;
    gettimeofday(&t, NULL);
    srand(t.tv_usec * t.tv_sec);

    if (len != correct_len) return 1;
    for (i = 0; i < correct_len; i++) {
        if (key_input[i] != correct_key[i]) {
            diff = key_input[i] - correct_key[i]; 
            if (diff < 0)
                diff = -diff;
            // delay stops brute force attack
            wait_time += diff;
        }
    }

    random_time = rand() % 10;
    usleep(10000 * (wait_time + random_time));

    return wait_time > 0;
}
```

Comment: Start by looking at which cases are leading to the *early termination* of the function.

Comment: The function terminates early when the password length is not right..

Comment: Which gives you a way of determining the length right away. Right? It is important piece of information.

Comment: Yes, the password consists of six characters. I'm just not sure how to go further than that.

Comment: Not an easy one I must admit.

Comment: Well, you can use a semi-brute-force approach. Have 5 characters fixed. Start with one character and run this code on each possibility few hundred of times. It shouldn't take too long, and calculate the *average* running time. This should effectively eliminate the randomness. Once you get the shortest average time, you can say with some confidence that you have one correct character. Fix it and proceed to the next one.

Comment: and notice that the difference - and therefore the wait - will get lower when you get closer to the correct one

Comment: Actually you can use even more heuristic approach. You don't have to try *all* of the possibilities, as the closer the character to the correct one, the shorter the waiting time, so you can do a kind of binary search. But I believe it is unnecessary complication.